# How do I insert a value to a foreign key field with my PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql

My code is to insert values posted from a form into a table.
CODE:

```
    1 $email1 = $_POST['txtemail'];
    2       $user1 = $_POST['txtuser'];
    3       $date1 = $_POST['txtdate'];
    4       $subject1 = $_POST['txtsubject'];
    5       $percent = $_POST['txtpercent'];
    6       $percent1 = (string) $percent;
    7       $query = "insert into personal_record values '','$email1','$user1','$date1','$subject1','$percent1'";
    8       $result = mysql_query($query,$link);
```

This is my code and it gives error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near
>   ''','jugal_patel2007@yahoo.co.in','Jugal','29
>   Mar 2011 13:28:42','jquery','40'' at
>   line 1

Please help me asap...!
Please do help.

Comment: You are missing brackets: It needs to be `VALUES ( ..... )`

Comment: Also, your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parenthesis arround the list of values :

```
insert into personal_record 
values ('','jugal_patel2007@yahoo.co.in','Jugal','29 Mar 2011 13:28:42','jquery','40')
```

And, as a sidenote, you really must **escape your data** using [**`mysql_real_escape_string()`**](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string), to prevent [**SQL Injections**](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/SQL_injection) !

So, here, you'd probably end up with something that would look a bit like this :

```
$email1_safe = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtemail']);
$user1_safe = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtuser']);
$date1_safe = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtdate']);
$subject1_safe = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtsubject']);
$percent_safe = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtpercent']);
$percent1_safe = mysql_real_escape_string((string) $percent);
$query = "insert into personal_record values ('','$email1_safe','$user1_safe','$date1_safe','$subject1_safe','$percent1_safe')";
$result = mysql_query($query,$link);
```

Additional notes :

- Are you sure the percentage is a string in your database ? If not, no need to pass it as a string, just use an integer or a decimal/float
- You should also specify the list of columns-names in the insert query, just to be sure

Comment: Thnks mate...!
It is a varchar datatype...! Anyway thanks to remember me.

Comment: Also I am not able to run two queries a time on a single page in php. You have any idea what it can be...?

Comment: Hu... Odd *(it might be better to ask this as a distinct separate question, with the relevant portion of code, error messages, and all)*

Answer (score 1):

change the query var:

```
$query = "insert into personal_record values 
           ('','$email1','$user1','$date1','$subject1','$percent1');";
```

as per @[Pekka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka)'s suggestion:
You are missing brackets: It needs to be `VALUES ( ..... )`

Answer (score 0):

You can start with placing brackets around the values:

```
"insert into personal_record values ('','$email1','$user1','$date1','$subject1','$percent1')"
```